# How to pass a youtube video's audio url as ffmpeg source

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, youtube-dl, discord.net

Im trying to get my discord bot to play the audio from any youtube videos using the video's url from youtube-dl (the audio url) as the ffmpeg path/source. I got it to work kind of but, while testing, the ffmpeg throws an error in the middle of the audio and the process ends. Here is the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt9d8.png

I've tried to play the same exact song by downloading it and using the file's path as ffmpeg source path and it worked fine.

Here is how i start the ffmpeg process:

```cs
            return Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
                Arguments = $"-xerror -i \"{path}\" -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            });
```

{path} is the audio url from youtube-dl process. (can also see the url in the error screenshot)

And here is how i get the link from youtube-dl:

```cs
Process youtubedl;


                ProcessStartInfo youtubedlGetTitle = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = "youtube-dl",
                    Arguments = $"--get-title --get-duration --get-url {url}",
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false
                };
                youtubedl = Process.Start(youtubedlGetTitle);
                youtubedl.WaitForExit();
```

{url} is a normal youtube video link.

I just started working with ffmpeg and youtube-dl so there probably are some stupid rookie mistakes that i'm not aware of. I would appreciate any guidance and/or explanation of what I did wrong.

Comment: You need to full pathname of the ffmpeg.exe and {path}.  The process class has no environmental variables (like PATH) so you need to include full path.

Comment: the {path} is the audio url, if that's what you mean. The url I get with the youtube-dl code. It works tho, but it closes half way through and gives the error in the image i provided.

Comment: I would run from cmd.exe prompt.  The exception  says that the speed is wrong.  Running from command line will give better error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the `youtube-dl` output directly into `ffmpeg`, this way both of them execute together as part of a parent process.

Not 100% sure this will fix your issue, but it's worth a shot.

Here's a code sample that does that in Windows:

```
// Note that 'query' can be both a youtube video URL or a search term (ex: "africa by toto")
private Process CreateStream(string query)
{
    return Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = $"/C youtube-dl.exe --default-search ytsearch -o - \"{query}\" | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    );
}
```